# Is there any way to extract graph viewer from arangoDB

Tags: javascript, arangodb

Can I extract graph viewer part alone from ArangoDB web UI and integrate that into my web application?

Is this possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. And I bet it's to limiting as well.
What do you want to achieve in your web application? There a lot's of libraries that can visualize graph data (like http://js.cytoscape.org/) and you can use Foxx to offer API endpoints that return the right data when requested by your app (hiding graph traversals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keylines or cytoscape js for graph visualization, if you are looking for purpose made libraries. Otherwise you can use a lower level library like D3.